# Minimize an Eclipse RCP tray application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, system-tray

I have an Eclipse RCP tray application. When I run it from Eclipse IDE environment it runs fine. But when it runs as an Eclipse product (standalone exe) it always show a title bar with three buttons (min/max/close) as you see below. I am running Windows 10. Why? How can I suppress this small window/shell.

[image]

I am calling the following method from **preWindowOpen**.

```
   private void minimize() {
        IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
        configurer.setInitialSize(new Point(50, 0));
        configurer.setShowCoolBar(false);
        configurer.setShowStatusLine(false);
        configurer.setShowMenuBar(false);
        configurer.setShellStyle(0);

        configurer.getWindow().getShell().setVisible(false);
        configurer.getWindow().getShell().setMinimized(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works in Eclipse Helios but is failing in Neon. I believe some of libraries has changed regarding minimizing a window.